# SimpleDiskCache inputStream bad number format

Tags: android, caching, android-lru-cache

I'm using the SimpleDiskCache code ([github link](https://github.com/fhucho/simple-disk-cache)) to cache a few video files to disk for an Android app I'm working.
Here's how I put the video file to cache:

```
OutputStream  fil =  videoCache.openStream(newData.getObjectId().toLowerCase());
fil.write(videoInBytes);
fil.flush();
fil.close();
```

And here's the code where I want to retrieve the video file from cache:

```
InputStream in = videoCache.getInputStream(newData.getObjectId().toLowerCase()).getInputStream();
File videoFile = Utils.createFile(Utils.TYPE_VIDEO_FILE);
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(videoFile);
IOUtils.copy(in, os);
os.close();
in.close();
```

The only problem is that I get a IOExption: read failed: EBADF (Bad file number). Here's the stack trace:

```
06-29 18:47:21.422: W/System.err(19393): java.io.IOException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
06-29 18:47:21.422: W/System.err(19393):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:442)
06-29 18:47:21.430: W/System.err(19393):    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:179)
06-29 18:47:21.430: W/System.err(19393):    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
06-29 18:47:21.430: W/System.err(19393):    at com.google.api.client.util.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:51)
06-29 18:47:21.430: W/System.err(19393):    at com.google.api.client.util.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:87)
06-29 18:47:21.430: W/System.err(19393):    at com.google.api.client.util.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:56)
06-29 18:47:21.430: W/System.err(19393):    at com.licenta.mementoapp.datafragments.VideoFragment$1.done(VideoFragment.java:151)
```

Does anyone have any ideea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: What about this answer?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584755/read-failed-ebadf-bad-file-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the input stream is closed before being used. You have to comment the snapshot.close() call at line 59 and close the inputstream yourself when you're done.

```
public InputStreamEntry getInputStream(String key) throws IOException {
    DiskLruCache.Snapshot snapshot = diskLruCache.get(toInternalKey(key));
    if (snapshot == null)
        return null;

    try {
        return new InputStreamEntry(snapshot, readMetadata(snapshot));
    } finally {
        //snapshot.close();
    }
}
```